# How to diminish CPU usage in linux c application (detached multithread)?

Tags: c, linux, cpu-usage

I eager to know which situation makes increased cpu-usage in checking top information to process written by me.

below is my environment.

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo 
system type             : CN3010_EVB_HS5 (CN5010p1.1-500-SCP)
processor               : 0
cpu model               : Cavium Octeon+ V0.1
BogoMIPS                : 1000.00
wait instruction        : yes
microsecond timers      : yes
tlb_entries             : 64
extra interrupt vector  : yes
hardware watchpoint     : yes, count: 2, address/irw mask: [0x0ffc, 0x0ffb]
ASEs implemented        :
shadow register sets    : 1
kscratch registers      : 0
core                    : 0
VCED exceptions         : not available
VCEI exceptions         : not available

# cat /proc/softirqs 
                CPU0       
      HI:          0
   TIMER:      37673
  NET_TX:          1
  NET_RX:      63481
   BLOCK:          0
BLOCK_IOPOLL:          0
 TASKLET:     241456
   SCHED:          0
 HRTIMER:          0
     RCU:      45060
# 

# cat /proc/stat 
cpu  6890 0 7591 11217 324 691 17637 0 0
cpu0 6890 0 7591 11217 324 691 17637 0 0
intr 3872174 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3557213 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 30852 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2530 0 6328 275165 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 88 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
ctxt 7152106
btime 1387517330
processes 1956
procs_running 2
procs_blocked 0
softirq 454085 0 44350 1 74147 0 0 282595 0 0 52992


**Cpu(s): 20.6%us, 23.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 15.0%id,  0.0%wa,  2.2%hi, 39.3%si,  0.0%st**
Mem: 45220K used, 50560K free, 0K shrd, 0K buff, 17568K cached
Load average: 0.52 0.72 0.52
  PID USER     STATUS   RSS  PPID %CPU %MEM COMMAND
  800 root     S       5076     1 75.3  5.2 core
 2104 root     S       2448   848  0.0  2.5 sshd
 ....
```

--> core is my process(with multithread) that has about 22 threads for doing jobs.
shortly, one thread to collect wireless packet, one thread changes wifi-frequency using netlink library. I'm not sure but I think that makes increased cpu-usage.

I don't know to control this situations, how to approach, 
Which part do I check?

below is my thread style.

```
while(1) {
 do jobs;
 sleep(x);
}
```

--> switched to

```
while (1) { 
 sleep(x);
 do jobs;
}
```

Can't resolve it. How to handle this issue? which part do I check ?

Please help me. I don't want to upgrade CPU.

Comment: You should explain much more what is your application actually doing. Why have you 22 threads? Wnhy don't you want the CPU to be used?

Comment: Shortly, My task collected wireless frames and analyse them. I want to know which case is to make cpu usage increased. I think it's not sable if not estimating CPU usage. Randomly CPU usage approached to peak (100%) I want to how to track this situations and also what cause this.

Answer (score 1):

You would generally use a profiler to determine where your application is spending its time.

Newer Linux kernels have a very low overhead profiler built in, which can trace in and out of kernel space as well, named `perf`. You can `perf record` your application and then run `perf report` to see what it did.

Comment: Or `perf top -p <PID>`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using OCTEON+ CN5010 cpu.    As an advanced perf improvement task, you could utilize OCTEON **simple-exec** programs (on Linux, or on separate cores natively), to get a further performance boost.

Paxym